# Duplicate rows by linq

Tags: c#, linq

Can you please help to replicate "for" statements that appear below into linq expression?

```
List<RawData> rawList = [{ "address":"adr1","id":[11,12,13],"city":"NYC"},{"address":"adr2","id":[22,23],"city":"Boston"}, {"address":"adr3","id":[77],"city":"Chicago"}];

List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
foreach (var item in rawList)
{
    foreach (var id in item.idList)
    {
        Data d = new Data
        {
            id = id,
            address = item.address,
            city = item.city
        };
        list.Add(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flattening in LINQ is done with [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method:

```
var res = rawList
    .SelectMany(item => item.idList
        .Select(id => new Data {
            id = id,
            address = item.address,
            city = item.city
        })
    ).ToList();
```

Once you understand what it does, the rest is self-explanatory.